# How to know the declaration kind of symbol in TypeScript compiler?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to build a code analysis tool following the [Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

Right now the app below can print out `p`, `Person`, `age`, `walk`.

But how to know `Person` is interface, `walk` is function, etc.? Thanks

**// app.ts**

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';

const userAppFile = './user-app.ts';
const apiFile = './api.d.ts';

const program = ts.createProgram([userAppFile, apiFile], ts.getDefaultCompilerOptions());
const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
const sourceFile = program.getSourceFile(userAppFile);

function printApi(node) {
  const symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(node);

  if (symbol) console.log(symbol.name);

  ts.forEachChild(node, printApi);
}

printApi(sourceFile);
```

**// api.d.ts**

```
interface Person {
  age: number;
}

declare function walk(speed: number): void;
```

**// user-app.ts**

```
const p: Person = { age: 10 };
walk(3);
```

Comment: Worth noting that in the example there's no reason to get the symbol. You can tell by looking at the node's kind. For example: `node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.FunctionDeclaration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the flags on the symbol.

I.e.:

```
if(symbol.flags & ts.SymbolFlags.Class) {
   // this symbol is a class 
} else if (symbol.flags & ts.SymbolFlags.Interface) {
   // this is an interface 
}
```